# Accepting files: namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination opens Finder window

Tags: cocoa, file, browser, drag-and-drop

I have a `NSView` to accept files from all the sources - local and remote. I use `NSFilesPromisePboardType` to accept remote files like images dragged from the browser. Here is the code I use to get dropped images to be copied into my folder:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSPasteboard * pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSDragOperation sourceDragMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];

    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilesPromisePboardType])
    {
        [sender namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:_fileStorageFolder];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

And now I have noticed 2 issues:

1. "Looked for HFSPromises on the pasteboard, but found none." warning
   is printed into the debug console.
2. Finder opens a new window to show and highlight the newly downloaded file.

**What is the correct way to receive files from browser without any warnings and Finder windows?**

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am running OSX 10.7.5 Lion.

Comment: Can you paste your more code here??

Comment: @hussain Shabbir: I've updated the source code in my question. This is a simple performDragOperation method. And I am just trying to accept 'promised files'.

Comment: Let's start with confirming this Finder issue. Does anyone see the same behaviour?

Comment: Anyone? It seems to be a common case. I am sure someone has faced the same difficulties...

Comment: where did you get _fileStorageFolder from ?

Comment: @MobileBloke, this is my own internal ivar.

Comment: Ah ok - thats the method that is telling Cocoa where you want to put the file, not where its currently stored.  Its not very clear from the Method name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answering my own question.**
There was nothing wrong with my code. It was the latest version of Google Chrome that opened Finder window after you drag&drop file from the browser to any location on your computer.

I found a bug-report for Google Chrome, tested Opera and Safari - everything is ok.

Sorry for bothering.